# How to transfer a value/object bottom to top in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Reactjs makes it really simple for data injection, we can inject data via parent element throught `this.props` or `this.state` objects. As for transfer value bottom to top, we can specify a `ref` attribute and then use dom methods get or edit it.

What if I want to transfer an object like thus:

```
var Editor = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var editor = new CodeMirror(this.getDOMNode());
    this.editor = editor;
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="editor"></div>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Editor />
      <button onClick={this._save}></button>
    );
  },

  _save: function() {
    // now I'm confused how can I get `editor` object?
  }
});
```

I did thought about transfer it through attribute like: `data-editor`, but if there is any elegant or recommend way in reactjs handle such situations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to "transfer" here. Usually components communicate back to their owners via callbacks passed as props.

Comment: @FelixKling I made some modification, take a look

Comment: Could you describe what data you would want to "transfer" from the Editor component? Normally you would either pass a callback from it’s parent or just send the data to whatever data storage you have (f.ex backbone/flux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. One is to assign a `ref` to the element and expose a method to get the editor or just the value:

```
var Editor = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
    var editor = new CodeMirror(this.getDOMNode());
    this.editor = editor;
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="editor"></div>
    );
  }

  getEditor: function() {
    return this.editor;
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Editor ref="editor"/>
      <button onClick={this._save}></button>
    );
  },

  _save: function() {
    var editor = this.refs.editor.getEditor();
  }
});
```

Comment: I even thought about `<Editor>.editor` ... thanks a lot